# Best Practice: Multiple Correlations with the same Variable

Tags: correlation, repeated-measures, multiple-comparisons

I am facing the issue that I want to test the correlation between one variable and multiple other variables. The data stems from an Experiment, where I have a control variable of which I want to test it's relationship with several factors from a within subject design. All variables are (somewhat) continuous. 
The only idea I came up with was (in my case) eight different correlation and control for Type I Error. There must surely be a better way, right?

Greetings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly; What you're interested in is is a "Multivariate Multiple Regression" or just "Multivariate Regression". I don't know what software you are using, but you can do this easily in R.